# Pass accentuation on query (javascript) (GET)

Tags: javascript, url, utf-8

I need to pass portuguese(BR) accentuation on a query, this is my javascript function:

```
        if (str.length == 0){ 
        document.getElementById("pacientes_hint").innerHTML="";
        return;
        }
        if(str.length > 2){
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                else{// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
                    document.getElementById("pacientes_hint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
                }
                xmlhttp.open("GET","pacientes/busca/"+str, true);
                xmlhttp.send();
        }
```

I tried escape(str) and encodeURI without success, thanks

@EDIT:

This is the php function

```
function busca(){
    $q = utf8_decode(urldecode($this->uri->segment(3)));
    echo $q;
    $q = str_replace("%20", " ", $q);
    $query = $this->model_pacientes->pegarLike($q);

    foreach($query as $k){
        echo "<div id='resultados_hint'>" . "<a href='#' onclick='clicar(this.firstChild.data);'>" .$k['Prinom']. "</a></div>";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

[encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent):

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","pacientes/busca/" + encodeURIComponent(str), true);
```

Comment: tried this and got a javascript error, this returned on the console:
http://(...)/pai/index.php/pacientes/busca/%25E9 404 (Not Found)

Comment: It looks like `str` doesn't contain what you expect it to contain. What does `alert(str)` before opening the connection say?

Comment: PS: Posted the php function aswell

Comment: alert(str) say exactly what I write, I just tried; "ééé" and it outputed "ééé"

Comment: The problem is that `str` as the PHP generates it doesn't produce an existing URL in combination with `pacientes/busca/`. The escaping as well as the rest of the JavaScript code seems to be correct.

Comment: I don't quite understand it, so my php function is incorrect ? What do you suggest?

Comment: The JS should construct correctly escaped URLs now. The new problem is that the URL doesn't exist (404 (Not Found)). I suggest that you try to figure out why your code produces non-existent URLs (eg., trying to use `echo $k['Prinom'];` in your PHP code to see if the value is correct).